# How to Calibrate Android Accelerometer & Reduce Noise, Eliminate Gravity

Tags: android, filter, accelerometer, noise, calibration

So, I've been struggling with this problem for some time, and haven't had any luck tapping the wisdom of the internets and related SO posts on the subject.

I am writing an Android app that uses the ubiquitous Accelerometer, but I seem to be getting an incredible amount of "noise" even while at rest, and can't seem to figure out how to deal with it as my readings need to be relatively accurate.  I thought that maybe my phone (HTC Incredible) was dysfunctional, but the sensor seems to work well with other games and apps I've played.

I've tried to use various "filters" but I can't seem to wrap my mind around them.  I understand that gravity must be dealt within some way, and maybe that's where I am going wrong.  Currently I have tried this, adapted from a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638864/filtering-accelerometer-data-noise), which refers to an example from the iPhone SDK:

```
                accel[0] = event.values[0] * kFilteringFactor + accel[0] * (1.0f - kFilteringFactor);
                accel[1] = event.values[1] * kFilteringFactor + accel[1] * (1.0f - kFilteringFactor);


                double x = event.values[0] - accel[0];
                double y = event.values[1] - accel[1];
```

The poster says to "play with" the kFilteringFactor value (kFilteringFactor = 0.1f in the example) until satisfied.  Unfortunately I still seem to get a lot of noise, and all this seems to do is make the readings come in as tiny decimals, which doesn't help me all that much, and it appears to just make the sensor less sensitive.  The math centers of my brain are also atrophied from years of neglect, so I don't completely understand how this filter is working.

Can someone explain to me in some detail how to go about getting a *useful* reading from the accelerometer? A succinct tutorial would be an incredible help, as I haven't found a really good one (at least aimed at my level of knowledge).  I get frustrated because I feel like all of this should be more apparent to me.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, and of course I can provide more samples from my code if needed.

I hope I'm not asking to be spoon-fed too much; I wouldn't be asking unless I've been trying to figure it our for a while. It also looks like there is some interest from other SO members.

Comment: Let me know if you get any leads on the "eliminate gravity" part, my hovercraft side business is *this close*!

Comment: Haha Jon, you didn't hear? Google fixed gravity. They'll be releasing the API soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a correct reading from the accelerometer you need to use the equation speed = SQRT(x*x + y*y + z*z). Using this, when the phone is at rest the speed will be that of gravity - 9.8m/s. So if you subtract that (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH) then when the phone is at rest, you will have a reading of 0 m/s. As for noise, Blrfl might be right about cheap accelerometers, even when my phone is at rest, it continuously flickers a few fractions of a metre per second. You could just set a small threshold e.g 0.4m/s and if the speed doesn't go over that, then it is at rest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply bobby! This is just what I was looking for.  I'll have to try this out and I will post my results once I get a chance.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that this answer is rather drastically incorrect, as explained in [this question on Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57523/do-you-use-the-magnitude-equation-to-get-speed-from-an-accelerometer).

Comment: there is a difference between acceleration and speed. You are measuring acceleration (m/s^2) and not speed (m/s). Gravity is 9.8m/s^2 and not 9.8m/s.

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

**Accuracy.** If you're looking for high accuracy, the inexpensive accelerometers you find in handsets won't cut the mustard.  For comparison, a three-axis sensor suitable for industrial or scientific use runs north of $1,500 for just the sensor; adding the hardware to power it and turn its readings into something a computer can use doubles the price.  The sensor in a handset runs well below $5 in quantity.

**Noise.**  Cheap sensors are inaccurate, and inaccuracy translates to noise.  An inaccurate sensor that isn't moving won't always show zeros, it will show values on either side within some range.  About the best you can do is characterize the sensor while motionless to get some idea how noisy it is and use that to round your measurements to a less-precise scale based on expected error.  (In other words, If it's within ±*x* m/s^2 of zero, it's safe to say the sensor's not moving, but you can't be precisely sure because it could be moving very slowly.)  You'll have to do this on every device, because they don't all use the same accelerometer and they all behave differently.  I guess that's one advantage the iPhone has: the hardware's pretty much homogeneous.

**Gravity.**  There's some discussion in the [`SensorEvent` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) about factoring gravity out of what the accelerometer says.  You'll notice it bears a lot of similarity to the code you posted, except that it's clearer about what it's doing.  :-)

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful reply, Blrfl.  Cleared up some of the more conceptual problems I've been having, and confirmed I'm not crazy for noticing the fluctuation in values coming from the accelerometer.

Answer (score 1):

How do you deal with jitteriness? You smooth the data. Instead of looking at the sequence of values from the sensor as your values, you average them on an ongoing basis, and the new sequence formed become the values you use. This moves each jittery value closer to the moving average. Averaging necessarily gets rid of quick variations in adjacent values.. and is why people use the terminology Low (frequency) Pass filtering since data that originally may have varied a lot per sample (or unit time) now varies more slowly.

eg, instead of using values 10 6 7 11 7 10, you can average these in many ways. For example, we can compute the next value from an equal weight of the running average (ie, of your last processed data point) with the next raw data point. Using a 50-50 mix for the above numbers, we'd get 10, 8, 7.5, 9.25, 8.125, 9.0675. This new sequence, our processed data, would be used in lieu of the noisy data. And we could use a different mix than 50-50 of course.

As an analogy, imagine you are reporting where a certain person is located using only your eyesight. You have a good view of the wider landscape, but the person is engulfed in a fog. You will see pieces of the body that catch your attention .. a moving left hand, a right foot, shine off eyeglasses, etc, that are jittery, BUT each value is fairly close to the true center of mass. If we run some sort of running averaging, we'd get values that approach the center of mass of that target as it moves through the fog and are in effect more accurate than the values we (the sensor) reported which was made noisy by the fog.

Now it seems like we are losing potentially interesting data to get a boring curve. It makes sense though. If we are trying to recreate an accurate picture of the person in the fog, the first task is to get a good smooth approximation of the center of mass. To this we can then add data from a complementary sensor/measuring process. For example, a different person might be up close to this target. That person might provide very accurate description of the body movements, but might be in the thick of the fog and not know overall where the target is ending up. This is the complementary position to what we first got -- the second data gives detail accurately without a sense of the approximate location. The two pieces of data would be stitched together. We'd low pass the first set (like your problem presented here) to get a general location void of noise. We'd high pass the second set of data to get the detail without unwanted misleading contributions to the general position. We use high quality global data and high quality local data, each set optimized in complementary ways and kept from corrupting the other set (through the 2 filterings).

Specifically, we'd mix in gyroscope data -- data that is accurate in the local detail of the "trees" but gets lost in the forest (drifts) -- into the data discussed here (from accelerometer) which sees the forest well but not the trees.

To summarize, we low pass data from sensors that is jittery but stays close to the "center of mass". We combine this base smooth value with data that is accurate at the detail but drifts, so this second set is high-pass filtered. We get the best of both worlds as we process each group of data to clean it of incorrect aspects. For the accelerometer, we smooth/low pass the data effectively by running some variation of a running average on its measured values. If we were treating the gyroscope data, we'd do math that effectively keeps the detail (accepts deltas) while rejecting the accumulated error that would eventually grow and corrupt the accelerometer smooth curve. How? Essentially, we use the actual gyro values (not averages), but use a small number of samples (of deltas) a piece when deriving our total final clean values. Using a small number of deltas keeps the overall average curve mostly along the same averages tracked by the low pass stage (by the averaged accelerometer data) which forms the bulk of each final data point.