# Samsung Smartphone accelerometer readings - trying to make sense

Tags: android

I am trying to record accelerometer values for a project using my smartphone. At static (phone completely at rest), attached file shows the readings I am seeing. I understand that this is not the most accurate accelerometer and there will be noise (which probably reflects the flickering value of all axes), but:
1. Why is the z value ~9.5m/s2 and not 9.81 m/s2?
2. Why arent x and y values completely 0 m/s2. x is closer to 0 but y is ~0.2m/s2.

I made sure my phone is as close to level in x and Y as possible. I know i need to apply some sort of smoothing to the data to take out the noise but why isnt the z axis exactly 9.81 m/s2?
EDIT: Phone is a Samsung Note 4
[image: Trace of the data]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4880733/295004 and an even older post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638864/filtering-accelerometer-data-noise

Comment: I saw this post. It is a good explanation for how to take noise out. But it does not explain why the value of gravity is being reported as 9.5 instead of 9.81 m/s2.

Comment: You don't mention what device/OS you are using (many different Samsung phones). Honestly you could either have a bad device or one that has over time become mis-calibrated. Regardless the If you need 'accuracy' you can calculate the offsets in your app as a setup step similar to how you are doing your testing.