# Smooth Compass for Android 2.2

Tags: android

I've been creating Compass for Android and I found several codes online but none of them provide example for smooth animation for the compass.

The url provided me the starting point in creating the compass..

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/08/simple-compass-sensormanager-and.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply a low pass filter to smooth the raw data. A low pass filter only allows through (to "pass") the low frequencies, and gets rid of the high frequencies, which are probably mostly noise (which will cause your compass to be jittery). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638864/filtering-accelerometer-data-noise) would probably be suitable for what you want.

Comment: Isn't this high pass filter?

Comment: A high pass filter lets through high frequencies and discards the lower frequencies, not what would be wanted in this case