# Accelerometer data in several android devices are different

Tags: android

I have observed the accelerometer data in several android devices are different in same place with same orientation.

I am developing a game based on accelerometer X and Y data and it is working fine with tablet, but unusual result in android phones.

Please suggest to overcome this issue.

Thanks,
Biplab

Answer (score 0):

This is natural because every device has different hardware specifications, that means that they also have different accelerometer implementations each having different noises in their readings. Even the time bettween two consecutive polls intitialized with the same sensor delay flag (such as `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME`) will probably differ in different devices. I suggest you apply filtering in your data for smoother readings.

- See [here](http://blog.thomnichols.org/2011/08/smoothing-sensor-data-with-a-low-pass-filter) for [low pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter).
- See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1736623/1482726) for [high pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter).

The examples are not in java but they will give you the idea.