# Plot angle on screen with OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am in a process of researching and stuck with my research. As the title states that I want to draw the x,y,z coordinates system on the screen on that I want to plot the Angle.

There are various things that I am not sure about. I am a Android developer at some what intermediate level but I have not worked with graphics system. So here are my confusions,

1. I want to use Accelerometer but I learnt that Gyroscope is better option to calculate the Accelerometer. I want to cover as much devices I can so which is the best option in terms of accuracy and device coverage.
2. Can I draw the coordinates system without OpenGL but drawing lines or the OpenGL is good option? Also does every device supports OpenGL?

These questions are for a headstart. I know I haven't mentioned any code and can be down voted  because some guys say lack of code is lack of research but how can I start coding without clearing things?

Comment: @CenterOrbit, may be you could point me to right direction as I seen your post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864223/how-to-read-android-accelerometer-values-in-a-stable-and-accurate-way.