# How do I normalize accelerometer sensor values to an relative scale?

Tags: android, accelerometer, normalization, android-sensors

Different devices have accelerometers manufactured by different manufacturers.

Say I want to categorize vibrations recieved from various devices into one of the following scales :

1. `LOW_MOVEMENT`
2. `MEDIUM_MOVEMENT`
3. `HIGH_MOVEMENT`

How can I devise a scale such that -

`LOW_MOVEMENT` of one device is `LOW_MOVEMENT` of every other device when subjected to the same vibrations. And so on for `MEDIUM_MOVEMENT` and `HIGH_MOVEMENT`?

The only data android gives me about the make of the accelerometer is **accelerometer resolution** and **maximum range of accelerometer**.

P.S. I plan on normalizing `x^2 + y^2 + z^2` under root.

Comment: I was also searching for same. You might find this one helpful [Gravity Sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864223/how-to-read-android-accelerometer-values-in-a-stable-and-accurate-way)