# Android Compass doesn't point North and keeps changing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, rotateanimation

So, I have been working on fixing this bug in my Android Compass for 2 days now.
Basically I am trying to build a Qibla Compass using Xamarin.Android . The First step should be to build a Compass that points to North.

> I have translated the JAVA code from  [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000120/Android-Compass) tutorial for my Compass to show proper North .

`I am simply rotating my Relative Layout which contains my Compass Image whenever Sensor reading Changes.`

I have tried  tweaking code by intuition but  this simple Compass doesn't love staying at one place. I am just trying to hold the North of my Compass Image aligned to the Magnetic north.

*However my compass never shows the correct North also the North keeps changing.*

> To  check my device Compass indeed works I tested an App from Playstore and it ran pretty smooth.

My Activity :

```
public class QiblaDirectionActivity : Activity, ISensorEventListener
//all the right inherits done
```

My design code Snippet :

```
            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/qiblaRL"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/qiblaCompass"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/compass" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/qiblaArrow"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/needle" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

My BackEnd :

```
 float currentCompassDegree = 0f;
 public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
    {
       //I have checked the accuracy its high
        RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(currentCompassDegree,-e.Values[0], Dimension.RelativeToSelf, 0.5f, Dimension.RelativeToSelf, 0.5f);
        ra.Duration = 120;
        ra.FillAfter = true;
        qiblaRL.StartAnimation(ra);

        currentCompassDegree = -e.Values[0];

    }
```

I register my listener here :

```
protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        if (_sensorManager != null)
        {

            var mF = _sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.MagneticField);
            _sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, mF, SensorDelay.Ui);
            qiblaAdvice.Text= "(Align Device Properly)";
        }
        else
        {
            qiblaAdvice.Text = "(Device doesn't support Compass)";
        }



    }
```

And I unregister it here :

```
   protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();

        if (_sensorManager != null)
        {
            _sensorManager.UnregisterListener(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Magnetic field sensors will contain a lot of noise

You will need to sample and smooth it.

Here is an answer where someone converted the high pass filter sample from Apple/iOS to Android for Accelerometer readings, but I used it for other smoothing purposes and you can strip it from three axis' to one like I have done:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8323572/4984832

#### For "true" North vs. a magnetic North

You can look at the offset received from **your** current declination and adjust the reading you are getting from your sensor.

There are numerous question/answers regarding this, here is just one:

- [Calculate compass bearing / heading to location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308262/calculate-compass-bearing-heading-to-location-in-android)

> The declination of the horizontal component of the magnetic field from true north, in degrees (i.e. positive means the magnetic field is rotated east that much from true north).

- [getDeclination](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/GeomagneticField.html#getDeclination())
- [Android.Hardware.GeomagneticField.Declination Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Hardware.GeomagneticField.Declination/)

Interesting answer on compensating for Tilt and Pitch of your phone:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16386066/4984832

[Android Compass that can Compensate for Tilt and Pitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317599/android-compass-that-can-compensate-for-tilt-and-pitch)

Comment: Guess this should be it